# Finding the power series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{(z^2+1)(z+1)}{z^4-1}$ at $z=i$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, power-series

Find the power series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{(z^2+1)(z+1)}{z^4-1}$ at $z=i$

Here is my attempt:

we have $\frac{(z^2+1)(z+1)}{z^4-1} = \frac{(z^2+1)(z+1)}{(z^2+1)(z^2-1)} = \frac{z+1}{(z+1)(z-1)} = \frac{1}{z-1}$. Since we want the power series expansion at i, we can first pull out a $-1$ entirely, and add and subtract i from the denominator and obtain:

$-1\frac{1}{1-i-z+i}$ $= \frac{-1}{1-i}$ $\frac{1}{1-{\frac{z-i}{1-i}}}$. Then this can be transformed into $\frac{-1}{1-i}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{z-i}{1-i})^k$ $=$ $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)\frac{(z-i)^k}{(1-i)^{k+1}}$ $=$ $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{(i-z)^k}{(1-i)^{k+1}}$.

I just want to check to see if I'm making sense of this correctly, or If I made any faulty moves here. This is more of a calculus 2 question than it is a complex analysis question.

Comment: The moves are not faulty, except that you must require that $|z-i|<|1-i|=\sqrt{2}$ for it to be a convergent series (in the penultimate step).

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: No worries Joey

Comment: If I were to obtain the radius of convergence, it will only ever be convergent is we have that inequality you wrote right? I tried to get that it converges without that, but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: The power series will converge in when $|z-i|<\sqrt{2}$—as already mentioned—and will also converge if $|z-i|=\sqrt{2}$ but $z\neq 1$; however, it will diverge for all $|z-i|>\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes a lot of sense yeah, thank you again!